# error: passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 3 [-Werror=restrict]

Tags: c, pointers, printf, dynamic-memory-allocation

When I manually test my program it compiles and works fine but when I try to use the autograder in the terminal I get this error. I am new to C and do not understand what it means and how to fix it.

My code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
    
    char *s = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 100);
    char prev = argv[1][0];
    if(isdigit(prev)!=0){
        printf("%s","ERROR");
        return 0;
    }
    
    int count = 1;
    for(int i=1; i<strlen(argv[1]); i++){
        if(isdigit(argv[1][i])!=0){
            printf("%s","ERROR");
            return 0;
        }
        if(prev==argv[1][i]){
            count++;
        }else{
            sprintf(s, "%s%c%d", s, prev, count);
            count = 1;
        }
        prev=argv[1][i];
    }
    sprintf(s, "%s%c%d", s, prev, count);
    if(strlen(s) > strlen(argv[1])){
        printf("%s\n", argv[1]);
    }else{
        printf("%s\n", s);
    }
    free(s);
      
}
```

Comment: It means the string used as the **output** for `sprintf` cannot also be used as an **input** to `sprintf`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not allowed to sprintf a string to itself.  That is, you can't pass the string `s` as one of the source arguments to `sprintf` when `s` is also the destination.

See for instance [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf), under Notes:

> The C standard and POSIX specify that the behavior of sprintf and its variants is undefined when an argument overlaps with the destination buffer. Example:

```
    sprintf(dst, "%s and %s", dst, t); // <- broken: undefined behavior
```

You'll need to come up with a different way to concatenate the desired characters and numbers together.

Comment: Thank you! But how else would I be able to concatenate a string and integers together since I cannot use "strcat" either?

Comment: @thegrinch: For the single character, you can just place it in the `s` array where it belongs.  If `count` is always a single digit, you can add `'0'` to make it a character and do likewise.  If it's several digits, you could still use `sprintf` with just `%d`, taking as the destination a pointer to the end of the string so far.

Comment: What if that `sprintf` call was `sprintf(dst, "%p and %s", dst, t);` -- is it still undefined behavior? The `%p` means we aren't looking at the *contents* of dst, just at the *address*

Comment: @BryanPendleton: The exact wording from the C standard is "If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined."  So your `%p` is not a problem since it does not copy anything from `dst`.